# Stop Firefox Flash from exiting full screen mode when focus leaves

Tags: c#, flash, winapi, firefox, fullscreen

Currently whenever I put a Flash window in full screen mode with firefox, as soon as focus leaves the Flash screen to my "always on top" form, flash immediately exits full screen mode! Even when I set my form to not show in the taskbar this occurs. Now there must be some way to get around this as a similar Java application that is always on top doesn't cause the flash player to exit full screen mode when focus is lost to the Java program.

Does anyone have any thoughts on how to avoid this behavior? Just a note, this doesn't occur in Chrome, just Firefox.

Comment: I shudder to think of what UI horror you are trying to construct.

Comment: This could be an issue with Flash player, as Chrome runs it's own built-in version. That's why you're experiencing different behavior with both browsers.

Comment: But that doesn't explain how it works with Java. I'll post a bug report to Mozilla and see what they come up with.

Comment: You could set your "always on top form" to no-activate, so it would not get the focus, theoretically. But that's more a workaround than a solution.

Comment: How do you do that? Put something in the activating event of the form?

Comment: I added an answer for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could show the Form with no activation. This is possible with the Win32 Extended Window Style **WS_EX_NOACTIVATE**.

You have to override the CreateParams property of the Form to set this style:

```
protected override CreateParams CreateParams
{
    get
    {
       CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
       cp.ExStyle |= 0x08000000/*WS_EX_NOACTIVATE*/;
       return cp;
    }
}
```

But note that this style has some side effects for the form, e.g. during moving it isn't drawn anymore.

Comment: Can you apply them dynamically, like, can you change the CreateParams once the form is created or not?

Comment: Yes, you can change them later, but in another way. You need some further Win32 stuff to set the extended window style, have a look at **SetWindowLong** (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633591%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).